# update two models different in the same template with only one button "submit" using class based view(UpdateView)

Tags: django, python-3.x

i want to update two different models with one button.using class based view (UpdateView).
for example...

```
class AboutMe(models.Model):
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True)
class MoreAboutMe(models.Model):
    MySecondAdress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Do you have a question that you'd like help with?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, and the answer can be a little bit long. But it should respond mostly to your question.

First of all, i've modified a little bit your model architecture in order to keep things clean when we update the records. Basically i've added a `foreignkey` to the `MoreAboutMe` model:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class AboutMe(models.Model):
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True)


class MoreAboutMe(models.Model):
    adress = models.ForeignKey(
        AboutMe,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name='more'
    )
    MySecondAdress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then, i created a custom `Form` that can handles the two models fields:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from MY_APP import models


class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):

    adress = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)
    second_adress = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.AboutMe
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then, the view:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from MY_APP import models, forms


class MeView(UpdateView):
    # Here we'll use AboutMe as a base model that
    # UpdateView will handle automatically
    model = models.AboutMe
    template_name = 'about_me.html'
    # Add our custom form
    form_class = forms.CustomForm 
    # Here we add empty initials and we'll populate them later
    initial = {}

    def get_initial(self):
        """
        Add the initials of the AboutMe form
        Add the initial value of second_adress field of the form
        """
        base_initial = super().get_initial()
        # The bad part of this example
        # is i used the user's pk for thr DB queries
        # It's not safe in this case
        # this is why you need to update your model's architecutre
        base_initial['second_adress'] = models.MoreAboutMe.objects.get(
            adress__pk=self.request.user.pk
        ).MySecondAdress
        return base_initial

    def get_success_url(self):
        """Add success URL
           Here we used the user's pk value for the URL reverse
        """
        return reverse_lazy('about_me', kwargs={'pk': self.request.user.pk})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Add MoreAboutMe model to the context data
        if you want to acess to MoreAboutMe model's records
        in the about_me.html template and in the view's methods
        """
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['second_model'] = models.MoreAboutMe.objects.get(
            adress__pk=self.request.user.pk
        )
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Here the tricky part: We get the cleaned data from the form then
        we'll update manually the MySecondAdress field then let Django handles 
        the rest of fields using the UpdateView Mixin
        """
        second_adress = form.cleaned_data.get('second_adress', None)
        if second_adress:
            instance = self.get_context_data().get('second_model')
            instance.MySecondAdress = second_adress
            instance.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Add a sucess message using the django's message framework"""
        messages.success(self.request, 'Updated')
        return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from MY_APP import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('about-me/<int:pk>/', views.MeView.as_view(), name='about_me')
]
```

And finally:

**about_me.html**

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {{ message }}
{% endfor %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Bonus: Here is a demo**

**Before the Submit:**

[image: Before the Submit]

**After the Submit:**

[image: After the Submit]

**Note:** You need to update your model architecture in order to keep your records clean and also keep in mind that your app needs to scale in the future.

Comment: really.your answer make me happy as it's very helpful.so i want tank you for your help and your time.and i also wish that some day i can help other people as you do ................thaaaaaaaaaaaaank you brother

Comment: You're welcome :D And if this answer fullfills your needs accept it and in this whay you can thank me. And happy coding :D